# MongoDb: search only if it contains all ids within the array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking for an array of ids, inside another array, the problem is that if it contains at least one "id" it returns the result. The validation should be that it has to have all the "ids" that I am passing.

```
{ subcategories: { $in: [ ObjectId('61729d550e8fe20011cc57d2', ObjectId('61693f589a34340012b1d5d8'), ObjectId('61693f2c9a34340012b1d5b7') )] } }
```

example:

- `subcategories: ["61729d550e8fe20011cc57d2", "61693f2c9a34340012b1d5b7"]` -> this one should not appear, because it contains only 2 of the 3 I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `$all`.

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) says:

> The `$all` operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements

```
db.collection.find({
  subcategories: {
    $all: [
      "61729d550e8fe20011cc57d2",
      "61693f589a34340012b1d5d8",
      "61693f2c9a34340012b1d5b7"
    ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qcW9ndrld1e)